# Redirect after CURL POST doesn't change URL

Tags: php, curl

I have a form that sits on my site.  When the form is submitted, it needs to POST that information to an internal (or external) website, and then redirect the browser to that internal (or external) website.

The form is located on `https://www.mysite.com/form.php`

```
<?php
$urlToPostTo = 'https://www.mysite.com/postPage.php';
$urlToRedirectTo = 'https://www.mysite.com/redirectPage.php';

$curlConnection = curl_init($urlToPostTo);
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $valuesToPost);

curl_exec($curlConnection);
curl_close($curlConnection);

header("Location: $urlToRedirectTo");
exit;

?>
```

The form posts correctly using CURL, and the final page I see is `$urlToRedirectTo`, but the URL listed in the browser is still the `mysite.com` URL.

If the POST and Redirect pages are on an external domain, everything works fine.  The URL in the browser changes and everything.  It is only when it is a same-domain URL that it does this odd behavior.  Generally, it will be posted to an external URL, but I need it to work correctly for when it is an internal URL without having to write separate code.

Note: the URL to be posted to/redirected to comes to me as a variable - I don't know if it will point to an internal or external domain.

Any ideas on how to make it handle the internal redirection correctly (update the browser URL)?

Comment: You don't happen to have a space or a line feed in front of your php-tag?

Comment: @Maerlyn: No, iFrames are not being used.

Comment: @MartyMcVry: There are no spaces in front of the `<?php` tag, although there is other code above the CURL code.

Comment: @justanotherprogrammer can you give yo full code

Comment: hav you checked for curl_errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php.?

Comment: If your cURL does things and receives cookies (such as, login), your user will not access those cookies, so if the page where you redirect your user requires preseted cookie, it may fail. What is your purpose? A context should help to understand the problem.

Comment: It is a payment system.  An external site posts to my page with parameters for the form (what is required, fields to show, page to return to, etc).  When the person making the payment submits the form, I post the result of the payment back to the requesting site, and then redirect the page to their confirmation page.  The general scenario would be external system -> my system -> external system.  Of course, that scenario is working as expected.  The broken scenario is the less-common case: my system -> my system -> mysystem.

Comment: Curl isn't giving any errors.  The page redirects fine, the problem is that the url in the browser address bar doesn't change.

Comment: @justanotherprogrammer have you found the solution? I have the same question.

Comment: @MithilBhoras Sorry, no I don't.  I just tried to reproduce the issue and I couldn't.  I don't know if something has changed in the browsers (I usually use Firefox) or if I was doing something wrong in my testing 3 years ago.  Everything behaves as I would expect now.  I wish I had a better answer for you!